# $this->ci->input->post('something') not working codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, filter

So I have this issue, I a working on perfex crm, and I have an issue I want to add a filter and there is a custom filter called custom_view I want to add another one what I did is I copied the code of the custom_view and added one called custom_view_ads:

This is the view of the custome view

```
     <select name="custom_view" title="<?php echo _l('additional_filters'); ?>" id="custom_view" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                                       <option value=""></option>
                                       <option value="lost"><?php echo _l('lead_lost'); ?></option>
                                       <option value="junk"><?php echo _l('lead_junk'); ?></option>
                                       <option value="public"><?php echo _l('lead_public'); ?></option>
                                       <option value="contacted_today"><?php echo _l('lead_add_edit_contacted_today'); ?></option>
                                       <option value="created_today"><?php echo _l('created_today'); ?></option>
                                       <!-- <option value="first_ads_source_id"><?php //echo json_decode($ads) ?></option> -->
                                 
                                       <?php if(has_permission('leads','','edit')){ ?>
                                       <option value="not_assigned"><?php echo _l('leads_not_assigned'); ?></option>
                                       <?php } ?>
                                       <?php if(isset($consent_purposes)) { ?>
                                         <optgroup label="<?php echo _l('gdpr_consent'); ?>">
                                             <?php foreach($consent_purposes as $purpose) { ?>
                                             <option value="consent_<?php echo $purpose['id']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $purpose['name']; ?>
                                             </option>
                                             <?php } ?>
                                         </optgroup>
                                       <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
```

and this is the one I added

```
  <select name="custom_view_ads" title="<?php echo "Ads Filter" ?>" id="custom_view_ads" class="selectpicker" data-width="100%">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php 
                                       foreach($ads as $ad)
                                         { ?>
                                          <option value="<?php echo $ad['first_ads_source_id']; ?>"><?php echo $ad['ads_view_text']; ?></option>
                                          <?php   
                                        }
                                       ?>
                              </select>
```

when I do this it works it goes into the if but

```
if ($this->ci->input->post('custom_view')) {
    $filter = $this->ci->input->post('custom_view');
}
```

when I do it like this for the other one it doesn't work,

```
if ($this->ci->input->post('custom_view_ads')) {
    $filter = $this->ci->input->post('custom_view_ads');
}
```

what I think is happening is I need to add custom_view_ads somewhere else but I can't seem to know where
Thank you for your help!

Comment: you need to load ci instance first before calling $this->ci->input->post();

like this

$ci = &get_instance();

Comment: I am calling it as there are others in same page that works I just wanted to see if I should put the select name somewhere else @PrinceJohn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
$this->input->post('');
```

Instead

Comment: If you've found your answer, please mark the answer as the correct answer mate.